# Why is the image of a compact operator separable?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compactness, normed-spaces

Let $A$ and $B$ be normed vector spaces and let $S\in \mathscr{K}(A,B)$ be a compact operator.

> Question: How does it follow that the image of $S$ is separable?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- A countable union of separable sets is separable (if $S_j$ is separable, let $\left(x^{j}_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ be a dense sequence in $S_j$; then $\left\{x_n^{j},n,j\geqslant 1\right\}$ is countable and dense in $\bigcup_{j\geqslant 1}S_j$).
- A subset $K$ with compact closure is separable (consider the covers $\left(B\left(x,n^{-1}\right)\right)_{x\in K}$).
- $A=\bigcup_{j\geqslant 0}B\left(0,j\right)$ and $S(A)=\bigcup_{j\geqslant 0}S\left(B\left(0,j\right)\right)$.

Comment: Giraudo   and how see countable unions of separable sets is separable

Comment: @user89940 I have edited.

Comment: thanks, but think a litlte more, i'm confusing a little.... if i said $S$ is separable, so exist $F$ countable that $\overline{F}=S$, so $S$ must be closed? because $\overline{F}$ is a close subset. what means say $R$ subset *not close* is separable, means that $\overline{R}$ is separable? . because in this case if $T$ compact operator, say $Im(T)$ is separable, not always $Im(T)$ is closed. thanks

Answer (score 7):

The space is a countable union of balls centered in zero:
$$A = \bigcup_{n\in N}B(0,n).$$

The image of $B(0,n)$ is precompact, therefore, separable. Countable union of separable sets is separable.